# Highcharts column animation issue

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I'm having trouble getting stacked column chart to animate when I perform `setData` on the series.
If the dataset has a lot of data points and the value of each data point in the dataset is also larger, the chart does not animate.

Has anyone experienced this issue?

Here is the fiddle that works correctly:
https://jsfiddle.net/AdityaParab/3f8vb5L7/

And this the the same code with much complex dataset
https://jsfiddle.net/AdityaParab/ow6yaen7/

How do I make it so that the animations work fine with complex dataset?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to increase `animationLimit` property:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        animationLimit: 9e9
    }
}
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/c37mw1zj/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.animationLimit